# Can a religious person have a favorite number?

Tags: halacha, number

Can a religious person have a favorite number? I can't remember where, but I learned somewhere that having a favorite number is not allowed, because it is ascribing "luck" to something other than the only True Power, the Almighty. Does anyone know anything about having a favorite number?

Comment: Does favorite necessarily involve ascribing power to it?  Are you asking about even without ascribing power?

Comment: Yes, without ascribing power. Like if I'm a teacher and I make an assignment for my kids about their favorite number - is there anything wrong with that? Let's say it potentially leads them to ascribe some sort of power to it - is there anything wrong with that? Is it similar to the "yom shlishi" being double tov and people like to get married on Tuesdays type thing? Or is there some sort of kishuf/luck/power ascribing element involved?